# error: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been getting the following errors when I try to compile my project

ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

**build.gradle(app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.spars.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //add start
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
// Multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.3.0'
    //add finish
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

//added part xxx
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '27.1.1'
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**build.gradle(project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**And I'm getting the following error**

> ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library
>   dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0. 1]",
>   but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the
>   library will be unknown.
>
> Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1
>   -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
>   15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.0.1.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or
>   have transitive dependencies that lead to the art ifact with the
>   issue.
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@15.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-common@15.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-common@16.0.4
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@16.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database@3.3.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@15.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@16.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth@3.3.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl@16.3.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@16.3.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage@3.3.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore@3.3.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone@15.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@16.3.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@16.3.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@17.0.3
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth@15.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats@16.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.firebaseui:firebase-ui@3.3.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@15.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags@15.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-database@16.0.6
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base@15.0.0
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@16.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop@16.0.1
>   -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@16.0.0
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with
>   ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep endency paths to
>   the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle
>   plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b uild.gradle
>   file.

Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue probably arises due to your `Firebase UI version` not being compatible with the versions of the `other dependencies of Firebase` you are using (the other ones `require a higher Google Play Services version`).

If you look [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/3.3.1) you will see which versions your `Firebase UI` will require.

Maybe you should consider `updating your Firebase UI version`, because the current one is [4.3.1](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/4.3.1)

Comment: When I update the UI version , everything goes fine except cardView version becomes uncompatible

Comment: yes since you are using cardview 23.3 and 27.1.1 remove the 23.3 one from your gradle file then it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

Import your dependencies as follows

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'


implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

import the following line too..

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'
```

Comment: You can also play with version as you sync your gradle

Answer (score 0):

Update new possible answer for 2020, according to firebase document:

> The Firebase Android library firebase-core is no longer needed. This
>   SDK included the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics.
>
> Now, to use Analytics or any Firebase product that recommends the use
>   of Analytics (see table below), you need to explicitly add the
>   Analytics dependency: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0.

That means, you should remove firebase-core

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
```

and add firebase analytics

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
```